# Check if component existed or not VC++ 2008

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

i defined a label like this:

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
```

and i want this label to be created then showed when the user press a button
the problem that i'm facing is when the user hit the button again ,the label is created again ,so i tried to put if statement like this:

```
if(this->label2 == NULL){/*create the label*/}
```

but NULL is not declared as the compiler says ,, i tried (0) but still not working!
please advice me...!

Answer (score 1):

`nullptr` is the proper way to specify null for a managed reference in c++/cli.  It is equivalent to `null` in C#.

Comment: Thank you very much :),,, what if i want to delete a texbox ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  But it sounds like another question. :)